# http request delete and put

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest

Below is my code for HTTP request for getting and post. What I wanted to know is how to do HTTP request for delete and put. I have made it possible for get and post to work. I want to know how on the part of delete and put based on my code below. what to change in my postcode when I want to change it to delete? what is lacking? I wanted to delete using ID
like for example "id": 16,

```
let parameters = ["name": "test", "desc": "test" , "reward":"1.00" , "sched":"2018-04-05T11:49:51+08:00",  "occurrence":["name": "once"]
    , "status": "created",  "created_by": "test@gmail.com","created_for": "test.com"] as [String : Any]

guard let url = URL(string: "http://test.tesst.eu:8000/api/v1/test/") else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
request.httpBody = httpBody

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }

    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

get

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://test.test:8000/api/v1/test") else { return }

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }

    if let data = data {
        print(data)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: you can set your method in URLRequest with `request. httpMethod  = "get/post/delete...."`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one that differs is **GET** with the parameters are in the url itself , **POST & DELETE & PUT** are work the same way , just change the `httpMethod` parameter and specify `httpBody` if you wanted to , meaning

DELETE : means delete a resource from a specific url

PUT : place a resource in to a web server

//

```
let parameters = ["ID": "16"] as [String : Any]
guard let url = URL(string: "http://test.tesst.eu:8000/api/v1/test/") else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: []) else { return }
request.httpBody = httpBody
```

Comment: how about i wanted to delete data with an ID for example "id": 16, ?

Comment: send the id of that item in httpBody like post

Comment: what would be the parameter? can you show me some example based on my code above.

Answer (score 2):

You should go through difference between each method types. It will help you, what should you do and when.

---

#### PUT

Store an entity at a URI. PUT can create a new entity or update an existing one. A PUT request is idempotent. Idempotency is the main difference between the expectations of PUT versus a POST request.

The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI. If a new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request. If the resource could not be created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate error response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the problem. The recipient of the entity MUST NOT ignore any Content-* (e.g. Content-Range) headers that it does not understand or implement and MUST return a 501 (Not Implemented) response in such cases.

Modify the address with an ID of 1:

> PUT /addresses/1
>
> *Note: PUT replaces an existing entity. If only a subset of data elements are provided, the rest will be replaced with empty or null.*

```
urlRequestInstance.httpMethod = "PUT"
```

---

#### DELETE

Request that a resource be removed; however, the resource does not have to be removed immediately. It could be an asynchronous or long-running request.

The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human intervention (or other means) on the origin server. The client cannot be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action has been completed successfully. However, the server SHOULD NOT indicate success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends to delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible location.

A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an entity describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action has not yet been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been enacted but the response does not include an entity.

Delete an address with an ID of 1:

> DELETE /addresses/1

```
urlRequestInstance.httpMethod = "DELETE"
```

---

Here are nice tutorial references for you:

- [Understanding REST](https://spring.io/understanding/REST)
- [REST Methods](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)
- [What is the usefulness of PUT and DELETE HTTP request methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142652/what-is-the-usefulness-of-put-and-delete-http-request-methods)

Now you can try a sample code, answered by Sh_Khan