# Use of Delete method in REST application

Tags: html, rest, http

I have created a book library project using REST+JSON which has an HTML page having many options. One of them is delete, but I am unable to use it in  as HTML doesn't define it. Can any tell me how to use that HTTP method? Example:

```
<form action="rest/bklib/remove" method="DELETE">
Enter BookName:<input type="text" name="Bookname">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="delete">
<p>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should PUT and DELETE be used in forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms)

Comment: No, HTML forms can use GET or POST. Use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx) by Scott Hanselman could be helpful in your case.

From the post:

> One thing you can do is to "tunnel" HTTP Methods inside another HTTP Header. Basically you have a header that says "No, seriously, I know I got here via a POST, but use this one instead." You would still POST, but then you'd have "X-HTTP-Method-Override:PUT" as a header.

I haven't use it myself, but, hey, if Scott says it, I'd give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

DELETE is a http standard not a html standar. HTML only knows GET and POST. I did hear that HTML5 accepts PUT and DELETE, but I'm not sure.

For doing DELETE requests you should use Ajax or jquery. I also recommend you to use ajax for GET and POST.