# PUT, GET ,POST ,DELETE methods using djangorest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-templates, django-rest-framework-gis

I'm using django rest framework , I use the post and get methods and it works, but I didn't understand how to use PUT and DELETE, do I use it in the html forms like : method='PUT' ? but i read that the browsers assimilated it to a GET method , do I write fonctions in my code for PUT and DELETE??

-I read many articles about rest and restful and I didn't understand the difference between it some people says that its the same , and others no but dont clarify,when I use POST and GET can I say that it's RESTFUL

thank you

Comment: You wouldn't use REST methods from a form at all. If you just want forms, use the standard Django forms framework.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's been a recent development, HTML forms do not support PUT nor DELETE methods. (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods are part of HTTP, not HTML, [more on this topic in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms))

However you can send PUT and DELETE requests using an HTTP client, e.g. Python has a library called [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/) you can use to send requests. Or if you want to do so from the front-end, e.g. from a browser, you can use JavaScript lib capable of sending out HTTP requests (or the more recent `fetch()` that comes with modern browsers, or its [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for older browsers)

e.g.

```
>>> import requests
>>> req = requests.request('PUT', 'http://yourapi/resource')
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: As for second part of the question, I wasn't sure how to attribute and point you to this article that explains the different "levels of RESTfulness", so here it is: http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html