# form with delete method wont hit asp.net Core controller with HttpDelete ActionVerb

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, actionresult, http-verbs

I am using .Net Core 2.1

I have a smal form that hits the controller when I dont have any `ActionVerbs` on the controller. As soon as I add `method="delete"` to the form and `[HttpDelete]` on the controller I get 404. What am I doing wrong?

> C#

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int? productID, int? subscriptionID)
{
}
```

> HTML

```
<form method="delete" action="@Url.Action("DeleteProduct")">

<input name="productID" type="hidden" value="@product.ProductID" />
<input name="subscriptionID" type="hidden" value="@subscription.SubscriptionID" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
Tabort <i class="fa fa-trash trashIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

</form>
```

Comment: That doesn't work the way you think it does: Let's find these on google: https://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/binding-form-data-in-asp-net-web-api and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470980/delete-route-not-being-hit

Comment: It answerd my question.

Comment: I had it all wrong. I understand know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to hear! Sometimes understanding is key ;)