# Delete button is not working in list.gsp of Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

Here is my code

```
        <td>
            <g:form resource="${this.stock}" method="DELETE">
                <g:link id="${stock.id}" class="btn btn-primary" action="edit" resource="${this.stock}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
                <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
            </g:form>
        </td>
```

`Edit` button is working but `Delete` Button is not working. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Hard to make out what you are doing you have a form with method DELETE then inside it a link to action edit - please review your code and what you are attempting to actuall do. the form action is ??  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms is this a normal form if so it should be action="delete" or what ever action form should be going to

Comment: I'm using this form as a column of a table where I want to use 2 action (Edit & Delete). I have taken this code from show.gsp

Comment: So you've taken the code above from show.gsp & put it in your own gsp? What does the action look like that feeds the gsp?

Answer (score 0):

See [grails documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/form.html),

As mentioned there in last line, form method to use is either `GET` or `POST`, you cannot specify `DELETE` as form method type.

better if you use `<g:actionSubmit>`, instead of `<input type="submit"/>`
for more info on `<g:actionSubmit>`, see [this link](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)

Also mention action name, where it redirect on submition of form.

Hope this works, try this , and if you still have any queries , let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have given `<g:actionSubmit value="Delete" action="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure???')" />` but yet not working