# django delete model entry from selected form option

Tags: django

I have the following form displaying entries of a model for user settings. When selected, I would like that a button catches its pk and send it to a Delete view.Here is the current code but I am missing this part.

**user_detail template html**

```
                <form id="SettingsListForm"><label>&nbsp Settings List : &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</label>
                    {% if user.usersetting.first %}
                        <select class="form-control" name="settingslist" id = "settingslist" form="SettingsListForm" >
                            {% for settings in user.usersetting.all %}      
                                    <option value="{{ settings.file.url }}">{{ settings }} 
                                    </option>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="list-group-item">NO SETTINGS YET</li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" href="{% url 'my_app:setting_delete' pk=user.usersetting.last.id %}"></i></button>

                    {% block delete_setting_confirm_block %}

                    {% endblock %}
                </form>
```

**setting_confirm_delete html template with delete_setting_confirm_block**

```
{% extends 'login_app/user_detail.html' %}
{% block delete_setting_confirm_block %} 
    <h4> 
        ARE YOU <b>REALLY</b> SURE YOU WANT TO <b>DELETE</b> THIS SETTING ?
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-danger" value="Delete">YES</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-default" href="{% url 'login_app:user_detail' pk=user.id %}"><b>NO</b></a>
        </form>
    </h4>
{% endblock %}
```

**my_app urls**

```
url(r'^setting/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserSettingDeleteView.as_view(),name='setting_delete'),
```

**UserSettingDeleteView in my_app views**

```
class UserSettingDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = models.UserSetting
    template_name = 'my_app/setting_confirm_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('my_app:user_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.user.pk})
```

Somehow, a similar technique works fine when using listgroups:

**working sample in user_detail html**

```
        <ul class="list-group">
            {% if user.userdata.first %}
                {% for data in user.userdata.all %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ data }}<a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle" href="{% url 'my_app:data_delete' pk=data.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a><a href="{{ data.file.url }}" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle" download><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i></a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% block delete_data_confirm_block %}

                {% endblock %}
            {% else %}
                <li class="list-group-item">NOTHING RECORDED YET</li>
            {% endif %}

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `template.html`, you should create a form for deletion, like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'my_app:setting_delete' pk=user.usersetting.last.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle">
</form>
```

Because in HTML you can not send directly `PUT` or `DELETE`, you should *fake* it via a `POST` request. It will be useful to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms), it is explained well.

Your `UserSettingDeleteView` can be as simple as that:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class UserSettingDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = MyModel
    # Replace with the model you want to delete (User)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_app:setting_list')
    # After deletion, possibly you will want to redirect the user to the list view
```

The built-in [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) cares itself to find your model by the `pk` parameter you pass through your url and delete it, you just have to configure the `model` and `success_url` fields.

Now if you click on your **Delete** button, you should expect your desired entry to be deleted and the user to be redirected to the list view.

**EDIT:**

I forgot that you want to get this entry via options. Here you will have to use some JavaScript in order to find the currently selected element and send it's `pk` to your `DeleteView`.

At first, add `id`'s to your `option` tags, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="settingslist" id="settingslist" form="SettingsListForm">
    {% for settings in user.usersetting.all %}      
        <option value="{{ settings.file.url }}" id="{{ settings.id }}">{{ settings }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And then add some *jQuery*:

```
var settingId = $('#SettingsListName').find(":selected").attr('id');
```

In the end, you need to send `settingId` to the corresponding url, but I am not very familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @wencakisa, thanks for the comment. I have tried something similar you are suggesting but the problem seems to be with getting the pk of the selected element in the 'select' component. I just edited my question with more detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a hidden input in your form. Right now, nothing is passing through the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="del_setting" value="{{user.usersetting.last.id}}">
```

So your form would look like this

```
<form method="POST"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
  <input type="hidden" name="del_setting" value="{{user.usersetting.last.id}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-danger" value="Delete">YES</button>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-default" href="{% url 'login_app:user_detail' pk=user.id %}"><b>NO</b></a> 
</form>
```

You also probably should move this out of the current form in your user detail template so that you're not putting a form within a form:

```
{% block delete_setting_confirm_block %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the previously mentioned solutions would work so I guess the problem is the nested bootstrap select item which is supposed to display the `pk` of the setting. 
For simplicity I then removed the problem by using `list-group` instead

```
                <ul class="list-group">
                    {% if user.usersetting.first %}
                        {% for settings in user.usersetting.all %}
                            <li class="list-group-item">{{ settings }}<a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle" href="{% url 'my_app:setting_delete' pk=settings.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <label>Create a new setting...</label>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="list-group-item">Create a new setting...<a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% block delete_setting_confirm_block %}

                    {% endblock %}
                </ul>
```

As a workaround,this works well.