# PugJS adding question mark in form action

Tags: node.js, typescript, pug

PugJS adding question mark in form action

```
form(method="DELETE", action='/shortener/'+ item._id)
    button.btn.btn-delete(type="submit") Delete
```

The URL I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/shortener/6421f534e7c2fbc3293e83ad?
```

I also tried to get the url using fetch()

```
public async destroy(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
  await Shortener.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
  return res.status(204).json([]);
}
```

Comment: it's not pug: [Should PUT and DELETE be used in forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880506/4321299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE` is not a valid value for [the `method` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#method), so the browser ignores it and reverts to the default (which is `GET`).

When you submit a GET form a query string on the `action` is added (or replaced if there is one there already) which consists of a `?` followed by the key=value pairs of the form data (in this case there is no form data so you just get the `?`).

---

If you want to make a DELETE request then you need to use JavaScript instead of a regular form submission.

If you want to make a form submission to tell the server to delete something, then use `POST`, not `DELETE` (as a side effect, POST won't add the query string).